# How can I write a json file in S3 from a SAM Lambda function with Node

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to save a json file from a Lambda function with Node but the file is not showing in my s3 bucket. From what I found, I have to make some change in my template.yaml file but I don't know what it is. I'm getting a positive response from the api post call but nothing happens in the bucket.

How can I fiz this?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  webhook

  Sample SAM Template for webhook
  
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: webhook_nath/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /webhook
            Method: POST
    Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: "es2020"
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints: 
        - app.ts
```

```
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';
import  aws  from 'aws-sdk';

const s3 = new aws.S3();

export const lambdaHandler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    let response: APIGatewayProxyResult;

    try {

        s3.putObject({
            
            Body: JSON.stringify(event.body),
            Bucket: 'new-bucket-nath',
            Key: 'file_name.json',
            ContentType:'application/json'
           
        }).promise();   
    
        response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'worked',
            }),
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        response = {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'some error happened',
            }),
        };
    }

    return response;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to s3.putObject needs an await.

‘await s3.putObject‘

Comment: Man, I tried everything, with await, without and nothings works. From what I found out I have to specify the S3 bucket and the permissions on the template.yaml file. I tried some things but it didn't work as well